# An unexpected error has ocurred (firebase login) en terminal

Tags: angular, firebase

No me deja conectarme al Cloud Functions (FireBase) y me salta estos errores. Si le doy click al link, me redirecciona a un Auth (conectarme) pero si selecciono mi cuenta sale que la página localhost no se encuentra.

Aclaro que ya hice: `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`  y usé la flag `--debug`

```
[info] i  Firebase optionally collects CLI usage and error reporting information to help improve our products. Data is collected in accordance with Google's privacy policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and is not used to identify you.

[info] 
[info] Visit this URL on this device to log in:
[info] https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=525844363&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9005
[info] 
[info] Waiting for authentication...
[debug] [2019-12-16T18:14:15.143Z] Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: habilitaste en Firebase el signin con google en la parte authentication?

Comment: Lo solucioné con eso, gracias.